# I need to make to disappearance ImageView. How I can make it? It's the last one what I need to do

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to make to disappearance ImageView. How I can make it? It's the last one what I need to do.
I have piece of paper. I need to move it in basket and it will disappearance.

Main5Activity.kt
The file I realized piece of paper move. How realize delete piece of papre or disappearance?

```
package com.example.fairytale_quest

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main5.*

class Main5Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5)
        val actionBar = supportActionBar

        actionBar!!.hide()
        var listener = View.OnTouchListener(function = { view, motionEvent ->

            if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

                view.y = motionEvent.rawY - view.height/2
                view.x = motionEvent.rawX - view.width/2
            }

            true

        })
        draggableImage.setOnTouchListener(listener)
    }
}
```

xml file with pieace of paper and wastebasket

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Main5Activity">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/pop"
            android:id="@+id/draggableImage" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:contentDescription="draggable"/>
    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/basketwaste"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="121dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.026" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `imageView2.visbility = View.Gone`

Comment: Can you help me again? How I can get X and Y coordinate my imageView? I want realize that when I drag piece of paper in basket it will disappearance